# Filter off Duplicates in VBA

Tags: vba

I want to filter off the Duplicates in VBA. I know there is a method called RemoveDuplicates

```
Columns(ColumnNumber).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1)
```

This method deletes the duplicates whereas I want to filter off the duplicates only. How do I do it?

Need some guidance on this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 Columns("A:A").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:= _
    Columns("A:A"), Unique:=True
```

If you want the Filtered values in separate column. Try

```
  Columns("A:A").Select
  Columns("A:A").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy,    CriteriaRange:=Columns( _
            "A:A"), CopyToRange:=Range("C1"), Unique:=True
```